# Using a Published var to observe a switch case in a Publisher with Combine

Tags: swift, enums, combine, publisher

I have an `enum` case which is a `@Published` var in an `ObservableObject` class. What I'm trying to do is observe changes to the `term` var defined below and update an `annualRate` publisher.

Below is the `@Published` var

```
@Published var term: MortgageTerm = .thirtyYear
```

The `MortgageTerm` enum is defined as follows:

```
public enum MortgageType: Int, CaseIterable {
    case tenYear     = 10
    case fifteenYear = 15
    case twentyYear  = 20
    case thirtyYear  = 30
}
```

I'm trying to get this `annualRate` defined so it observes changes to the `term` var above:

```
public lazy var annualRate: AnyPublisher<Double, Never> = {
    var output: Double
    $term
        .map { switchCase -> Double in
            switch switchCase {
            case .tenYear:
                output = self.rates.tenYearFix
            case .fifteenYear:
                output = self.rates.fifteenYearFix
            case .twentyYear:
                output = self.rates.twentyYearFix
            case .thirtyYear:
                output = self.rates.thirtyYearFix
            }
            
            return output * 0.01
        }
        // FIXME: Result of call to `eraseToAnyPublisher()` is unused
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}()
```

I'm getting this warning at the line for `.eraseToAnyPublisher()`. What am I mucking up and how do I fix it?

This is where the `rates` are coming from:

```
private lazy var rates: AverageRate = {
    let rateMock = AverageRate(thirtyYearFha: 2.873,
                                thirtyYearVa: 2.858,
                                tenYearFix: 2.068,
                                fifteenYearFix: 2.358,
                                thirtyYearFix: 3.054,
                                fiveOneArm: 2.898,
                                sevenOneArm: 2.972,
                                twentyYearFix: 2.756)
    
    return rateMock
}()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, you don't have a `return` statement inside your `annualRate` `{ }`. You have two statements -- one defining `output` and the second creating the publisher. If you just had *one* statement, it would be considered an implicit return and you wouldn't have the error.

I think you can refactor very slightly and get rid of the `var output` since every value is getting modified by the same amount. So, you can just tack on another `map`:

```
public lazy var annualRate: AnyPublisher<Double, Never> = {
    $term
        .map { switchCase -> Double in
            switch switchCase {
            case .tenYear:
                return self.rates.tenYearFix
            case .fifteenYear:
                return self.rates.fifteenYearFix
            case .twentyYear:
                return self.rates.twentyYearFix
            case .thirtyYear:
                return self.rates.thirtyYearFix
            }
        }
        .map { $0 * 0.01 }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}()
```

Now, there's just *one* statement, which is considered an implicit return and nothing is unused.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been fiddling with this longer than I care to admit today. I need to get used to the `Combine` way of doing things

Comment: No problem. You also could have moved the `var output` *inside* of the `map` closure, but it is a little Swift-ier to just do the second `map`, I think. The implicit return is not Combine specific, but is a more recent Swift feature.